# Scala - Playframework 2.3 - serve a partial HTML

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an app that is a backend and does not have views. Now I have to add the "terms of service" and I my idea is to serve a partial HTML. I do not want to have all the HTML because then I will embed this in different places (WEB and Mobile).

this is my view

```
@{
  <h1>Hello world!!!</h1>
}
```

My controller

```
object TosEndpoints extends Controller {

  def get() = PublicApi.async {
    Ok(views.html.tos("Terms of service"))
  }
}
```

my routes.conf

```
GET   /tos               controllers.TosEndpoints.get()
```

I can not serve the content of the view

I get for example this error

```
app/views/tos.html.scala:1: identifier expected but '{' found.
[error] @{
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove the arguments I get the same error.

If I pass one argument and bind it in the view (as suggested @AliDehghani) I get this error
    app/views/tos.html.scala:1: ')' expected but ':' found.
    [error] @(tos: String)

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Thank you @Ryan, I hope now is more clear, if not, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling the view with too many arguments. You should either fix the render part by removing the extra argument:

```
Ok(views.html.tos())
```

Or change your view in a way that it accepts the passed argument, something like following:

```
@(tos: String)

<h1>Hello world!!!</h1>
<p>@tos</p>
```

Then you can render the view by:

```
Ok(views.html.tos("Terms of service"))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited my post to explain what happens.

Comment: Replace `PublicApi.async` with `Action` temporarily, see what happens

Comment: Finally it was that I named the file in the wrong way, instead of tos.scala.html I named the file tos.html.scala

Comment: If you edit your answer and add this information I mark as the correct answer. thank you.